# Facebook Application UTF-8 Issues in PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I am developing a Facebook Iframe application using PHP which opens an RSS feed from another site and displays a selected item from the feed. The RSS feed if UTF-8 encoded, however when I display the selected item I get the characters displayed as ISO-8859 whatever.

Example: "Donâ€™t" instead of "Don't"

This is my working code:

```
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->load('https://www.otherwebsite.com/rss.php');

  foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
            $title = $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
            if ($title == $chinese->getAnimal()){
              $horoscope = $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
           }      
  }    
  echo 'Your horoscope : ' . $horoscope . '';
 }
```

I am using version 5.2 of PHP. Any questions or suggestions will be gratefully accepted, I am still learning PHP so I may have missed something obvious to a more skilled practitioner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have a proper html header and meta for UTF-8 on your webpage i.e.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='eng' lang='en'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<title>WAMP</title>
<meta name='Description' content='Website Under Construction' />
</head>
<body>
CONTENT
</body>
</html>
```

Also try casting the string to UTF-8 before echoing it.

```
$horoscope = utf8_encode("Your Horoscope : $horoscope");
echo $horoscope;
```

Comment: Thanks skibulk, adding the header did the trick. My brain was in FBML mode and I didn't do a header as I hadn't in the past. But this is a plain old iframe and needed standard html. I also tried the encode but It's too late for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo 'Your horoscope : ' . utf8_encode($horoscope);
```

However that will only work for ISO-8859-1.

Alternatively try

```
$in_encoding = "ISO-8859-1"; //replace with the encoding of the RSS feed
echo 'Your horoscope : ' . iconv($in_encoding, "UTF-8", $horoscope);
```

Answer (score 0):

`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1')`

Try adding this to the very top of your php file.